# Apple In-App Purchase

Tags: iphone, ipad, in-app-purchase

While testing In-App-Purchase in the SANDBOX ENVIRONMENT on the device, I'm logging the following error :

**Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=0 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" UserInfo=0x2916a0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot connect to iTunes Store}.t**

I'm able to retreive the product id's which i registered through iTunes Connect. I'm displaying data related with these products as in a table view along with Buying option.
When i try to buy a product a transaction is initiated but it doesn't ask me for any test user details & i get the error as mentioned above.

I'm providing the code which I implemented.

```
    //the below code is for RETREIVING THE PRODUCT id's

#pragma mark Store kit
-(IBAction)sendProductInfoRequest{
NSLog(@"sendProductInfoRequest");

NSSet *identifiersSet=[NSSet setWithObjects:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@".15April2011"],[NSString                          stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"15April201102"],nil];
SKProductsRequest *productRequest=[[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:identifiersSet];
productRequest.delegate=self;
[productRequest start];
NSLog(@"completing sendProductInfoRequest");
}

- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{
NSLog(@"yoooo!");
NSLog(@"The product request didReceiveResponse :%@",[response description]);
NSLog(@"The products are :%@",[response.products description]);

NSLog(@"The invalidProductIdentifiers are:%@",[response.invalidProductIdentifiers description]);

NSArray *products=response.products;



for(SKProduct *currentProduct in products){

NSLog(@"THE Product price is :%@",currentProduct.price);
NSLog(@"THE Product description is :%@",currentProduct.localizedDescription);
NSLog(@"THE Product title is :%@",currentProduct.localizedTitle);
NSLog(@"THE Product's product identifier is :%@",currentProduct.productIdentifier);

}

}



/the BuyProducts method is called when user clicks buy button related to a particular product
-(IBAction)BuyProducts
{
if ([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments])
{
[self makePaymentRequestForThisProduct:isbnText.text];
}

}



-(void)makePaymentRequestForThisProduct:(NSString*)productID

{
SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProductIdentifier:productID];  
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
}



/I have added the transaction observer in applicationDidFinishLaunching method of AppDelegate
//Transaction Observer is a class

TransactionObserver *observer;
observer = [[TransactionObserver alloc] init];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:observer];

//the TransactionObserver.m class

@implementation TransactionObserver


- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
    {

switch (transaction.transactionState)
        {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                [self completeTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
NSLog(@"failed transaction");
                [self failedTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}

- (void) completeTransaction: (SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
NSLog(@"successful purchase");
  //  [self recordTransaction: transaction];
//[self provideContent: transaction.payment.productIdentifier];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
}

- (void) restoreTransaction: (SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
NSLog(@"restored incomplete transaction");
//   [self recordTransaction: transaction];
//   [self provideContent: transaction.originalTransaction.payment.productIdentifier];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
}

- (void) failedTransaction: (SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{

NSLog(@"The error description is:%@",[transaction.error description]);
if (transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled)
    {
if(transaction.error.code == SKErrorUnknown) {
NSLog(@"Unknown Error (%d), product: %@", (int)transaction.error.code, transaction.payment.productIdentifier);
UIAlertView *failureAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle :@"In-App-Purchase Error:"
message: @"There was an error purchasing this item please try again."
  delegate : self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"otherButtonTitles:nil];

[failureAlert show];
[failureAlert release];
}

if(transaction.error.code == SKErrorClientInvalid) {
NSLog(@"Client invalid (%d), product: %@", (int)transaction.error.code, transaction.payment.productIdentifier);
UIAlertView *failureAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle :@"In-App-Purchase Error:"
message: @"There was an error purchasing this item please try again."
  delegate : self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"otherButtonTitles:nil];
[failureAlert show];
[failureAlert release];
}

if(transaction.error.code == SKErrorPaymentInvalid) {
NSLog(@"Payment invalid (%d), product: %@", (int)transaction.error.code, transaction.payment.productIdentifier);
UIAlertView *failureAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle :@"In-App-Purchase Error:"
message: @"There was an error purchasing this item please try again."
  delegate : self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"otherButtonTitles:nil];
[failureAlert show];
[failureAlert release];
}

if(transaction.error.code == SKErrorPaymentNotAllowed) {
NSLog(@"Payment not allowed (%d), product: %@", (int)transaction.error.code, transaction.payment.productIdentifier);
UIAlertView *failureAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle :@"In-App-Purchase Error:"
message: @"There was an error purchasing this item please try again."
  delegate : self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"otherButtonTitles:nil];
[failureAlert show];
[failureAlert release];
}
    }
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
}


@end
```

Comment: You don't have an internet connection?

Comment: @richard I'm getting the product info of all the products that i registered for my app at iTunes connect. Which means my Wi-Fi connection is active

Comment: sorry for reviving an old question but i am having the exact same problem now, could you find any other solution other than a hard reset?

Comment: For what it is worth, I had the exact same problem.  I found that the cause, at least for me, was having my device logged in with a real apple account rather than a test account.  I logged out and then everything worked as it should.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be ridiculous, but -- if you're certain your code is correct -- do a hard reset (full wipe) of your iPod (Settings => General => Reset => Erase All Content and Settings).

Comment: is there any chance that sandbox servers are down? Don't you think the code i've attached here is correct

Answer (score 1):

It also happens if you are logged in with some other iTunes Account. To test the In App purchase in Sandbox box you need to log out from any other account from Setting. Then launch your application and Do in App Purchase. When your account is asked enter the one you created as iTunes Test Account. This way your Sandbox environment would work perfectly. Hope this would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the Sandbox servers are down.

I am able to get product info but I get the same error when requesting a purchase

I checked the Apple Developer Forums and more people are having the same issue.
https://devforums.apple.com/index.jspa

I hope this saves someone some time some day, as I've spent 4 hours around this.