# In-App-Purchasing iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, ipad, in-app-purchase, storekit

I am facing problem on In-App-Purchasing in my iPhone/iPad application.

My Issues are :

1> What is the use of Shared Secret - Where we have to use this?.
2> How we can all our application form store?
3> How we can test our application?
4> To enable in app purchase - We need application on app store?

Please give me some guide line for implementing in app purchasing.

Thank you.

I am gone through the apple process to enable in app purchase but I dn't know what I missed in my steps that's why I need more clear steps to understand the In-App-Purchasing with in my application?

Basically I need full steps for In-App-Purchasing.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Start with reading the Apple "In App Purchase Programming guide": https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 1):

1)http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/RenewableSubscriptions/RenewableSubscriptions.html YOU CAN FIND YOUR ANSWER HERE.

2)Sorry, didn't get you on this one

3) To test in-app-purchase

step1: log into iTunes connect, Navigate to manage your applications-->add new application (FILL THE INFORMATION)--> Availability date can be set at a later stage, select the price range-->enter the METADATA.

step2: Navigate to contracts, Tax & banking section in Itunes Connect & complete the IOS PAID APPLICATIONS CONTRACT.(Enter bank details, tax & contacts).If your app is free complete IOS FREE APPLICATIONS CONTRACT as well.

step3: Navigate to the manage users section & create a TEST user account.

step4: ADD products to your application.

step5: Transfer the application to your device using developer provisioning profile. The developer provisioning profile  should use the SAME BUNDLE ID which was used while adding the application. before transferring the application navigate to settings--> store--> logout from any iTunes user account.

4) There IS NO NEED for APPLICATION TO BE ON APP STORE TO ENABLE IN APP PURCHASES.

Comment: I am gone through the apple process to enable in app purchase but I dn't know what I missed in my steps that's why I need more clear steps to understand the In-App-Purchasing with in my application?

Basically I need full steps for In-App-Purchasing.

Thank you.

Comment: can i know error which you are getting while trying to buy a product.

Comment: I am following this Guy...http://www.raywenderlich.com/2797/introduction-to-in-app-purchases. But I am not getting any kind of error in code but unable to fetcher the product details. Can you help me. Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5872788/in-app-purchase Add a button in your User interface & add this -(IBAction)sendProductInfoRequest method. Also ADD this delegate method - (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response. THIS WORKED FOR ME. Hopefully it will work for you.

Comment: I am facing this problem TestInApp[119:307] Problem in iTunes connect configuration for product: <MyProductID>.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what you exactly need

Apple has a really good documentation on The Store Kit framework.
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

I myself never created something for in-app purchase but to clarify a little bit.

I believe there are 2 ways to implement this
one is writing predefined stuff in youre source
for example, in infinity blade they let you buy extra gold.
The user asks for the list of available purchases from the app store the app store produces a list of in-app identifiers (which are predefined in code and on itunes connect)
the user selects for example "10.000 extra gold" for 0.99 dollar cents
The transaction will be made to the app store, the app store after succes returns a ok message in which the code should have a listener implemented that basically in this example add 10.000 to your "currentGold" variable.

The other way I don't know much about is connecting via an app to app store which in his turn connects to a server that is set up by you.
From what I can gather is that is what is being uses for level unlocks in for example sudoku games etc

as for Testing the purchase.
Whenever you have store kit implemented and try to connect it in the iOS Simulator.
The simulator automatically connects to a Sandbox envirenmont and therfore simulates the payment too